# Добавить к дате в строковом типе несколько дней

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с проблемой написания функции для добавления к какой-то некоторого количества дней. Честно говоря, даже не представляю, каким образом это можно осуществить.

Описание функции:

На вход поступает строка с датой в формате "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ", эту дату необходимо из строки перевести в собственно дату, прибавить (или вычесть) несколько дней к этой дате и перевести ее обратно в строку, желательно, сохраняя формат, в котором она поступила.

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо заранее!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51243699/3212712

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, решается это как-то так:

```
//Задаём формат даты
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
String date = "29.12.2020";
//Превращаем строку в дату
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

//Пусть надо прибавить 2 дня
int daysToAdd = 2;
//В новую (!) переменную сохраняем результат прибавления 2 дней
LocalDate incrementedDate = localDate.plusDays(daysToAdd);

//Приводим дату к строке, используя тот же форматтер
String incrementedDateString = incrementedDate.format(formatter);

//Выводим строку с новой датой
System.out.println(incrementedDateString);
```